# Bending array around an object

Tags: modeling

So I am trying to make the grate circled by red follow the route marked by black, I am not sure how to make it follow the whole path evenly however. How would one go about making the grate fill in the groove? I need the grate to fill in the groove marked by black without being deformed as well.

[image: Grate Fill area]

File download here: [image]

Comment: Add a curve which follows the object you created, then setup a curve modifier. The problem is that the curve modifier sometimes deforms the mesh quite strange (especially at sharp angles) and I don't know if it will work for you, guess you'll need to try :)

Comment: I was thinking curve but was worried about it deforming stuff, is there a setting that allows me to keep the vast majority of shape geometry intact?

Comment: And also is there a way to snap the curve to the geometry I want the array to follow so I don't have to line it up by hand?

Comment: You can combine array and curve modifier, if that was your question, but I'm sorry, don't know about the deform stuff

Comment: Can you add a sketch of how you expect the grate to curve in the corner?

Comment: I think you could apply the techniques from [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1drRNphACMc) to your model.

Comment: I want it to bend like this around a corner. https://gyazo.com/864c4d163a0b5bfb802d9b23746aa0e6

Comment: I used the bend modifier but I want to learn how to do it with array.